# Strange parsing json to xml in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, typescript, parsing

I have a strange problem. I work with nodeJS and I want to parse json to XML, then send it to remote WebService. So:
1. Download 'soap' and 'js2xmlparser' via npm
2. Create Client:

```
    function searchPerson(myObj:myObjRequestDto) {
  return soap.createClientAsync(urlWSDL)
    .then((client: any) => {
      const xmlString = x2js.parse("MyNode", searchExperianObject);
      console.log(xmlString);
      return client.search(xmlString, function (err, result) {
        if (err) { console.error(err); }
        ...
        }
```

What I got in console.log(err) :

```
Error: Cannot parse response at finish (...) at parseSync (...) at (...) at Request(...) ... and
<0>&lt;</0><1>s</1><2>o</2><3>a</3><4>p</4><5>e</5><6>n</6><7>v</7><8>:</8><9>E</9><10>n</10><11>v</11><12>e</12><13>l</13><14>o</14><15>p</15><16>e</16><17> </17><18>x</18> ...
```

... and rest of all XML in this tags.
But in in console.log(xmlString) everything is beautiful. 
I guess this is source of my error (this tags).

Comment: Are you sure your xmlString is actual finished from the parser before you send it to the client ?

Comment: I guess YES, because this error is after printing from console.log()